# Definition of rank for compact semisimple Lie group

Tags: lie-groups

Let $G$ be a compact semisimple Lie group. I have found to different definitions of its rank: One of them defined the rank of the Lie group to be the dimension of a maximal torus. The other definition defined the rank to be the dimension of a Cartan subalgebra in the Lie algebra. Do these definitions coincide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For semisimple Lie algebras, a Cartan subalgebra is a maximal abelian subalgebra, i.e., a maximal torus. So the definitions coincide.

Comment: It seems that "semisimple" is irrelevant here. See Théorème 2 (a), Section 2.2, Chapitre 9 of Bourbaki's Groupes et Algèbres de Lie.

Comment: @DougLiu In general, a Cartan subalgebra is not a maximal abelian subalgebra, but a maximal nilpotent subalgebra (consider a nilpotent Lie algebra). For semisimple, these two notions coincide. This is what I meant.

Comment: You are definitely right. But do we need "semisimple" for the OP's question?

Comment: I see. No. But I was assuming he only considers the semisimple case.